# php replace string with emoticon images. issue forming an array with mysql emoticon data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to replace any emoticon plain-text symbols (for example: :P :) :P :hello: :goodbye:) in the string $textmchat with the corresponding emoticon data stored in my MYSQL database (yes I know I should be using PDO). I'm getting: Notice: Undefined index: for code, emotion, smiley_url, smiley_width, and smiley_height with the code seen below. I haven't a clue what is wrong and any help would be appreciated. The data SELECTed in the MYSQL query does exist and is certainly not null.

```
// example text that needs to be replaced with smilies

$textmchat = 'lorem ipsum :) :) lorem ipsum :P lorem';

mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT code, emotion, smiley_url, smiley_width, smiley_height FROM phpbb_smilies WHERE display_on_posting = '1'")
or die(mysql_error());
    $smilies = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $smilies[$row['code']] = array($row['emotion'],  $row['smiley_url'],  $row['smiley_width'],  $row['smiley_height'] );

}
foreach($smilies as $key => $img) {
    $textmchat = str_replace($key, '<img src="images/smilies/'.$img['smiley_url'].'" alt="'.$img['emotion'].'" title="'.$img['emotion'].'" height="'.$img['smiley_height'].'" width="'.$img['smiley_width'].'" />', $textmchat);
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined $smiles?

Comment: Using PDO (or msqli) you could just do `$result = $statement->fetchAll();` and be done.

Comment: Your "array" definition is completely bogus, I suggest you start with the basics: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: Ushma Shah sorry I updated it

Comment: Gerald Schneider I can't figure out how to place the SELECT'd mysql data into an array so my foreach statement can replace all plain text emoticons with images. Is mysql_fetch_array the right command to fetch the data?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are using `mysql_fetch_array`, or `mysql_fetch_assoc`, or even `PDO`! Your PHP syntax is incorrect. There is a **huge** difference between what `"$code"` and `'$code'` will output.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// example text that needs to be replaced with smilies

$textmchat = 'dog cat fish LOL  :) :) jump duck :P dive';

mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT code, emotion, smiley_url, smiley_width, smiley_height FROM phpbb_smilies WHERE display_on_posting = '1'")
or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC){
    $smilies[$row['code']] = array($row['emotion'],  $row['smiley_url'],  $row['smiley_width'],  $row['smiley_height'] );
}
foreach($smiles as $key => $img) {
    $textmchat = str_replace($key, '<img src="images/smilies/'.$img['smiley_url'].'" alt="'.$img['emotion'].'" title="'.$img['emotion'].'" height="'.$img['smiley_height'].'"     width="'.$img['smiley_width'].'" />', $textmchat);
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{   Maybe the syntax in the while statement is not correct?